# Azure SignalR Service - swagger page

Tags: azure

When creating a new SignalR Service on MS Azure, it seems to be there a default swagger page that is wrongly configured (screenshot below). There is any way to disable it?

To reproduce the issue, on a SignalR Service instance, navigate to:

```
https://<yourservicename>.service.signalr.net/swagger
```

If it cannot be disabled, seems to be a light case to put the SignalR Service prone for Information Disclosure attacks.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/susSB.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/howto-network-access-control. You should be able to block the swagger page by Denying REST request. Let me know if that helps.

[image: signalr network access control]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ryan! However, why am I supposed to block request for a page that is wrongly configured and it is not requested by customer itself? I do not need a public Swagger... I suggest to escalate to Product Group :)

Comment: I noticed you had an open support ticket. I advise you mention this in the support ticket, but I will also bring this feedback to the product. I realize the current feature is opt-in, but you should still be able to apply that access policy.